# Creating ArrayBuilders in a Loop

Tags: c++, apache-arrow

Is there any way to create a dynamic container of `arrow::ArrayBuilder` objects? Here is an example

```cpp
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::size_t rowCount = 5;
  arrow::MemoryPool* pool = arrow::default_memory_pool();  
  std::vector<arrow::Int64Builder> builders;
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    arrow::Int64Builder tmp(pool);
    tmp.Reserve(rowCount);
    builders.push_back(tmp);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This yields `error: variable ‘arrow::Int64Builder tmp’ has initializer but incomplete type`

I am ideally trying to build a collection that will hold various builders and construct a table from row-wise data I am receiving. My guess is that this isn't the intended use for builders, but I couldn't find anything definitive in the Arrow documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do your includes look like?  That error message seems to suggest you are not including the right files.  The full definition for `arrow:Int64Builder` is in `arrow/array/builder_primitive.h` but you can usually just include `arrow/api.h` to get everything.

The following compiles for me:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <arrow/api.h>

arrow::Status Main() {
    std::size_t rowCount = 5;
    arrow::MemoryPool* pool = arrow::default_memory_pool();
    std::vector<arrow::Int64Builder> builders;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      arrow::Int64Builder tmp(pool);
      ARROW_RETURN_NOT_OK(tmp.Reserve(rowCount));
      builders.push_back(std::move(tmp));
    }
  return arrow::Status::OK();
}

int main() {
  auto status = Main();
  if (!status.ok()) {
    std::cerr << "Err: " << status << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

One small change to your example is that builders don't have a copy constructor / can't be copied.  So I had to `std::move` it into the vector.

Also, if you want a single collection with many different types of builders then you probably want `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<arrow::ArrayBuilder>>` and you'll need to construct your builders on the heap.

One challenge you may run into is the fact that the builders all have different signatures for the `Append` method (e.g. the `Int64Builder` has `Append(long)` but the `StringBuilder` has `Append(arrow::util::string_view)`).  As a result `arrow::ArrayBuilder` doesn't really have any `Append` methods (there are a few which take scalars, if you happen to already have your data as an Arrow C++ scalar).  However, you can probably overcome this by casting to the appropriate type when you need to append.

Update:

If you really want to avoid casting and you know the schema ahead of time you could maybe do something along the lines of...

```
std::vector<std::function<arrow::Status(const Row&)>> append_funcs;
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<arrow::ArrayBuilder>> builders;
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < schema.fields().size(); i++) {
  const auto& field = schema.fields()[i];
  if (isInt32(field)) {
    auto int_builder = std::make_shared<Int32Builder>();
    append_funcs.push_back([int_builder] (const Row& row) ({
      int val = row.GetCell<int>(i);
      return int_builder->Append(val);
    });
    builders.push_back(std::move(int_builder));
  } else if {
    // Other types go here
  }
}

// Later
for (const auto& row : rows) {
  for (const auto& append_func : append_funcs) {
    ARROW_RETURN_NOT_OK(append_func(row));
  }
}
```

Note: I made up `Row` because I have no idea what format your data is in originally.  Also I made up `isInt32` because I don't recall how to check that off the top of my head.

This uses `shared_ptr` instead of `unique_ptr` because you need two copies, one in the capture of the lambda and the other in the `builders` array.

Comment: To your second point about the casting. I am creating the schema up front which would already tell me the types each column needs. Are you aware of any facility within Arrow I can use to associate the Field type to its appropriate builder? Or is that something I can only do through casting?

Comment: Note that I also cannot use ArrayBuilder in the above example as it would yield `error: variable type 'arrow::ArrayBuilder' is an abstract class` . Might be bordering on a separate SO question but figured I'd comment here first

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<arrow::ArrayBuilder>` not `arrow::ArrayBuilder`  In c++ you can have a vector of pointers-to-abstract-base but you cannot have a vector of abstract-base.  `shared_ptr` (or any other pointer type) is fine too.  I'll update the answer with some pseudo-code of an approach you can take that avoids the casting using the schema ahead of time.

Comment: That is totally awesome. Thanks as always!